# Ceylon plugin failed in Android Studio

Tags: android, ceylon

I recently saw it article in infoq:

https://www.infoq.com/news/2016/09/ceylon-13-android-support

I installed the plugin in Android studio 2.2 without problems. But when In the Android view, Right-click on app > Configure Ceylon in this Module

I got it:

Error:Class com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.VariantScopeImpl does not implement the requested interface com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BaseScope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* (and hope) that if you update the Ceylon IDE plugin to the [very latest version](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/update/index?pr=idea&updateId=28918) which was released two days ago, then this bug will be gone.

Here's the [release notes](https://github.com/ceylon/ceylon-ide-intellij/releases/tag/1.3.0-1).

Answer (score 2):

This is actually a [bug in the ceylon-gradle-android plugin](https://github.com/ceylon/ceylon-gradle-android/issues/6), that has been fixed in 1.0.1.

Upgrade the version in `app/build.gradle`, resync the project and do `Tools > Ceylon > Reset Ceylon model` and it should work again.